# Is there a way to cancel Touches on Awake of a Screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm having an issue with a game I'm working on. As the user drags his character around the screen, if the character dies while dragging, I switch to the "dead" scene. The problem is that on the new scene there are two buttons using the new Unity UI. Buttons and if the player happens to have his finger over one of the buttons when the scene loads and lets go as a reaction they end up executing the button before they even see what was on the screen.

Is there a way I can say on Awake, Start or Enable to cancel all touches? Forcing the user to lift their finger off the screen and then tap the button they want after they digest the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO better user experience is to play an animation when the character dies. The animation could even be as simple as blurring or dimming the view slowly. Then the player has some time to react and he or she will quite likely end the ongoing drag.

If you still want to disable all touches, one work around could be to add boolean telling if any new touches has started at the new scene. Unfortunately, I am guessing that this will not work robustly:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool newTouchesInThisScene = false;

    void Update() {
        for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                newTouchesInThisScene = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks. Great idea. I agree with you on the slowing and dimming, just in the way it plays it has to switch over as it's an animated scene of how you died. This works great thank you.